# How do I use the bowtie method to multiply $(2x-27)(-x+15)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

[image]

The bowtie method seems like an easy concept to have down, but how is it used to multiply binomials such as $(2x-27)(-x+15)$?

Calculating the answer is not the problem, because I can get $(-2x^2+57x-405)$, I'm just not sure how to use this method to represent how to multiply the equation.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you don't have any problem multiplying out the product directly, then you don't *need* any bowtie mnemonics, and it would be pointless to spend effort on learning one.

That being said, you would draw something like

```
2x  -27
 |\ /|
 | X |
 |/ \|
-x   15
```

and then each of the lines in the bowtie corresponds to one term of the product. You get (in some order)
$$ 2x\cdot(-x) + 2x\cdot 15 + (-27)\cdot(-x) + (-27)\cdot15 $$
Then you just need to rearrange and simplify in order to get the answer you already know!
(And all in all it's probably the same calculation you're *already* doing, just without the silly diagram to remind you which terms to multiply).